# How to interface a simple keypad with the computer and mobile using PYTHON?

Tags: python, user-interface, keypad

The problem is that i want to interface my mobile phone with my computer using a keypad in between. The interfacing should be done in **Python** environment as this would help me in my further work. 
the things which i need is

1. inteface my computer with the keypad using python
2. interface the same keypad with a mobile phone

so that i can control the general features of my mobile phone with that keypad using the python code.

Comment: Brush up your understanding of mobile environment using documents from android or iphone. Read about bluetooth interface. Then come back and post or edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

The most general way to connect your computer to a phone would be over TCP/IP, likely delivered via WiFi to your phone.  If using an Android, BlueTooth would be another option, but iOS will not connect to unapproved BT devices.

Programming on the handset will likely have to be done in the native language.  It's an absolute requirement of iOS, and I'm not sure if you can use Python/Jython to build a full app on Android yet.

On the PC side, you could easily use Python, perhaps its `socket` module to talk with the handset over TCP/IP or pySerial's `serial` if you use BlueTooth RFCOMM/SPP; though managing the actual BT connection is very complex and very sensitive to drivers.